# Hello world program of dynamicallyModifiesClasspath() of Apache Nifi properties descriptor not working

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have a processor which depends on some jar as a dependency. However changes are made to the dependency jar quite frequenctly. So I want to be able to specify the jar path as a property of processor and let the nifi load the jar each time I modify the path in the property and restart the processor. This is supposed to be doable using [`dynamicallyModifiesClasspath`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.4.0/org/apache/nifi/components/PropertyDescriptor.Builder.html#dynamicallyModifiesClasspath) as explained in [this article](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/11/24/apache-nifi-class-loading). However I am unable to do this. Below is my code of hello world program using `dynamicallyModifiesClasspath` property:

(Below, Djl stands for "dynamic jar loading", a random prefix I guessed to name this hello world program.)

**DjlDependencyClass.java**

This is the class on which my nifi processor depends and I want to dynamically change its jar path in my nifi processor.

```
public class DjlDependencyClass {

    public static String getMessage()
    {
        return "DJL-DEPENDENCY VERSION-1";
    }
}
```

**MyDjlProcessor.java**

This is the nifi processor which depends on DjlDependencyClass.

```
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.lifecycle.OnScheduled;
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException;    
import org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessSession;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessorInitializationContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators;

import com.mycompany.djldependency.DjlDependencyClass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyDjlProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public static final Relationship MY_RELATIONSHIP = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("MY_RELATIONSHIP")
            .description("Example relationship")
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor pathToDjlDependencyJar = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("Djl Dependency JAR")
            .description("Djl Dependency JAR")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .dynamicallyModifiesClasspath(true)
            .expressionLanguageSupported(true)
            .build();

    private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;

    private Set<Relationship> relationships;

    @Override
    protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
        final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<PropertyDescriptor>();
        descriptors.add(pathToDjlDependencyJar);
        this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(descriptors);

        final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();
        relationships.add(MY_RELATIONSHIP);
        this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return this.relationships;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
        return descriptors;
    }

    @OnScheduled
    public void onScheduled(final ProcessContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
        System.out.println(DjlDependencyClass.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is how dependency inside pom is marked to have `provided` scope, so that the dependency jar will not be embedded inside nar:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>djl-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided </scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am testing this processor as follows:

[image]

Configuration of the processor:

[image]

I am getting following exception:

```
2019-05-27 17:01:54,536 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] com.mycompany.djl.MyDjlProcessor MyDjlProcessor[id=f8fa5750-016a-1000-ecc3-c19732119332] MyDjlProcessor[id=f8fa5750-016a-1000-ecc3-c19732119332] failed to process due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/djldependency/DjlDependencyClass; rolling back session: {}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/djldependency/DjlDependencyClass
    at com.mycompany.djl.MyDjlProcessor.onTrigger(MyDjlProcessor.java:76)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1122)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Am I doing something stupid here?

Please download both projects (nifi and dependency jar) [here](https://docs.zoho.com/file/epjrl7e542d0c001e4f82b5ffc48a1de06828).

Comment: why you specify the directory and not a jar as the classpath parameter value? what do you have in `...\djl\` folder?

Comment: Actually, I tried specifying both. I kept `djl-dependency-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in `C:\Mahesh\delete\djl`. Then, first I tried by setting processor property to `C:\Mahesh\delete\djl`. It didnt work. Then I tried setting property to `C:\Mahesh\delete\djl\djl-dependency-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Still didnt work.

Comment: @daggett any pointer please ? Am I missing anything stupid? Were you able to run my code?

Comment: i just know that there are standard processors that use this feature. For example: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-jolt-record-bundle/nifi-jolt-record-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/jolt/record/JoltTransformRecord.java#L155

Comment: Try dynamic class loading instead of static

Comment: Could be an issue with the file paths on windows, might be worth putting a directory or file validator on the property descriptor (depending which you are specifying) to make sure that NiFi thinks something is there before it even gets to the class loading

Comment: Did you annotate the processor with `@RequiresInstanceClassloading`?

Comment: @daggett what do you mean by "Try dynamic class loading instead of static"? Dynamic class loading in java is done with `Class.forName`, whereas static class loading is nothing but creating instance with `new` operator. Do you mean to say make that `pathToDjlDependencyJar` property instance member by removing `static` modifier?

Comment: @Mahesha999, exactly. But through classloader of the current class. Or maybe through context classloader... I believe it'll work.

Comment: Any link (/explanation) discussing "classloader of the current class" and "context classloader" please...(Tried running my code on nifi 1.9.2, didnt work, earlier I was on 1.5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API document for `PropertyDescriptor` mentions the following note:

> If a component contains a PropertyDescriptor where dynamicallyModifiesClasspath is set to true, the component must also be annotated with @RequiresInstanceClassloading, otherwise the component will be considered invalid.

I'm not sure whether that 'invalid' part still holds true but yeah, after updating your processor code to have it annotated with `@RequiresInstanceClassloading`, I was able to get it working.

Comment: Do you mean to say merely doing `@RequiresInstanceClassLoading public class MyDjlProcessor extends AbstractProcessor { .. }` made it to work? Not working for me. I am using NiFi version 1.5.0. can this be an issue?

Comment: Are you sure just annotating processor with `@RequiresInstanceClassLoading` should make it work? I just referred the standard `JoltTransformRecord` processor [linked](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-jolt-record-bundle/nifi-jolt-record-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/jolt/record/JoltTransformRecord.java#L155) by daggett in comments. That porcessor is not annotated with `@RequiresInstanceClassLoading`. But as noted by you, doc says processor should 
be annotated with `@RequiresInstanceClassLoading`. Is this version specific? Am on nifi 1.5.0.

Comment: Can you give your setup / environment specs?

Comment: Extremely sorry for the delayed response. Will share the code with you sometime today.