# How can I manage dependencies of external jar required by my custom processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have written a custom nifi processor. It has a dependency on a component which is built by another team. We frequently get new versions of this component. So, in order to avoid rebuilding custom processor by including a code of a component in a custom processor, we are [specifying path to component jar in processor's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325462/hello-world-program-of-dynamicallymodifiesclasspath-of-apache-nifi-properties) so that processor can load the jar dynamically.

However, I am unsure how should we manage dependencies of that component. We want deployment of the new version of the component as clean as possible. So how can we ensure that component also have all its dependency available when we deploy (copy-paste at the location specified in the processor's properties) it on NiFi server? I know we can ask the team to build a FAT JAR of the component.

1. But is this (FAT JAR) the standard approach?

   Also, I don't know whether it will be possible to build FAT jar due to licensing issues of dependencies.
2. Is there any other approach to ensure dependencies of the new component are available when deployed?
3. How it is handled by built / standard processors which come with Apache NiFi distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only answers #3, but...

All of the standard processors in Apache NiFi bundle the required dependencies into the NAR at build time through standard Maven dependencies.

Some processors make use of dynamicallyModifiesClassPath in order to add additional resources beyond what is typically required.

For example, the HDFS processors include the standard HDFS client for talking to an hdfs:// FileSystem, but there are many other client libraries that have their own implementation of the FileSystem and NiFi can't include them all, it may not even know about some of them. So the HDSFS processors have an "Additional Resources" property where you could specify the location of jars with additional FileSystem implementations.

Comment: I am trying to get exactly what you were suggesting. I am using `dynamicallyModifiesClassPath` property to specify a component jar on which my processor depends. So, should I **(1)** accept another `dynamicallyModifiesClassPath` property to specify path containing dependencies of component jar? OR **(2)** Include those dependencies in same path as component jar **(3)** Specify path as normal (non-`dynamicallyModifiesClassPath`) dependency and make component jar to load its dependency from this path. I believe you were suggesting point (3). Are (1) and (2) also ok?

Comment: 1 and 2 are really no different, all the jars/resources specified by all dynamicallyModifiesClasspath properties all end up in the same list of resource for the processor

Comment: I was saying that most of the time the primary dependencies of a processor are included at build time through Maven, and usually only additional non-required things are specified through dynamicallyModifiesClasspath

Comment: I was talking about dependencies of those "additional non-required things" which are specified through dynamicallyModifiesClasspath. (not the immediate dependencies of my custom processor) Are those dependencies also specified through dynamicallyModifiesClasspath ?

Comment: Yes typically there just be one property for "additional resources" where you specify anything that wasn't included at build time